# Retrieving files from sdcard in Android

Tags: android, image, file

In my application I'm retrieving files from sdcard and after checking is it .jpg oe .png image I'm storing path of file in File array. But I'm getting NullPointerException also the file path exists. What is wrong with following code. Please help

```
 File[] image;
  File f = new File("/sdcard/download");//or Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        int j=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++,j++) {
            File file1 = files[i];

            String myfile = file1.getPath().substring(file1.getPath().lastIndexOf("/")+1,file1.getPath().length()).toLowerCase(); 
            System.out.println("file is : "+files[i]);
            if(myfile.endsWith(".jpeg")||myfile.endsWith(".png")|| myfile.endsWith(".gif") || myfile.endsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                System.out.println("file is : "+files[i]);
                image[j]=files[i];//here i'm getting exception
                }
            }
```

exceptions-

```
  02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.zproject/com.my.zproject.ImportFile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at com.my.zproject.ImportFile.onCreate(ImportFile.java:76)
02-15 19:28:36.463: E/AndroidRuntime(12918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Comment: Also, don't hardcode the SD card. Use the Environment class instead

Comment: i have posted error log

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize array `image` like this

```
File[] image;
File f = new File("/sdcard/download");//or Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    image = new File[files.length]
    int j=0;
```